# Trouble installing bootstrap image gallery for Rails site

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/blueimp/Boo) tstrap-Image-Gallery

Though for someone who's relatively new, it's a bit vague to say copy directories into your website, so I'll walk you through what I did to help with troubleshooting.

*Btw, I found another post [Add Bootstrap-Image-Gallery to a Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013320/add-bootstrap-image-gallery-to-a-rails-project), but the problem there is that the instructions are the same level of vagueness, and I didn't want to install the bootstrap-addon-rails Gem because I'm trying to not install stuff I don't need and I don't need the other portions, as well as the fact that it appears the original gallery github has been updated more recently.*

1. Download github directory as a Zipfile
2. Open Zipfile, copy the "css"
   folder entirely into app/assets/stylesheets
3. ..., copy the "js"
   folder entirely into app/assets/javascripts
4. ..., copy the "img"
   folder entirely into app/assets/images
5. Copy the code exactly as is
   in the documentation into the site where I'm building the gallery

**Quick question:**
- Not sure what the "img" folder is doing when I copy it over. None of the code directly references it, and it doesn't appear to be used as the source for the images in the "Links" section of the gallery

**Anyways, the gallery is successful, but I have some problems with getting the images to load.**

1) I can't get the image files or thumbnails to load. I assume that the source is incorrect, but not sure how to fix. Currently, my images are stored in two places: assets/images/photos and assets/images/thumbnails. As such, the code that I'm writing is this:

```
<a href="assets/photos/X.jpg" title="X" data-gallery><img src="assets/thumbnails/X.jpg"</a>
```

Note that I read in another post that Rails assets pipeline requires you to use assets as the main directory, NOT images, as the gallery documentation would have you do, but I've tried every iteration of assets/photos, assets/images/photos/, images/photos and none have worked.

2) While my thumbnails have not worked, there are a 100 or so default images linked from flickr. I can't find these links anywhere in the source code I copied from the github, nor did I write it in myself, yet when I inspect element, there is a string of thumbnails in the Links section after the thumbnails that I put in, how do I get rid of these?

3) Clicking on any thumbnail pops out the lightbox carousel, which is great! But as it is, I can scroll by using left/ right arrow keys, or dragging the image using the mouse (i.e., a simulated swipe on a non-touch device). The arrows that I would have expected to appear given the code's use of glyphicon chevron left/ right and buttons for next, do not appear. How do I enable these?

Many thanks for any help at any of the problem areas above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out... dumb mistake, hope this helps someone else

Question 1 answer: You just have to add an extra forward slash in front of the img src, i.e., instead of "assets/image," it has to be "/assets/image".

Question 2 answer: All of this is in the file demo.js in the js folder that I copied. To remove, I just commented out all the code (put a /* before the code starts)

Question 3 answer: This appears to have fixed itself on refresh. No idea why.

Quick question answer: In the bootstrap-image-gallery.css file in the css folder that I copied, on line 71, there is a background url that is calling from the img folder that was also copied over. To the extent that I've found looking through the other files, this is the only place that is pulling from the img folder (it's pulling a loading symbol)